# Linq-To-Sql SubmitChanges Not Updating Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I've read multiple questions similar to this one but none are exactly my situation.

Using linq-to-sql I insert a new record and submit changes. Then, in the same web request, I pull that same record, and update it, then submit changes. The changes are not saved. The DatabaseContext is the same across both these operations.

Insert:

```
var transaction = _factory.CreateTransaction(siteId, userId, questionId, type, amount, transactionId, processor);

using (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = UnitOfWork.Begin())
{
    transaction.Amount = amount;

    _transactionRepository.Add(transaction);

    unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

Select and Update:

```
ITransaction transaction = _transactionRepository.FindById(transactionId);

if (transaction == null) throw new Exception(Constants.ErrorCannotFindTransactionWithId.FormatWith(transactionId));

using (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = UnitOfWork.Begin())
{
    transaction.CrmId = crmId;

    transaction.UpdatedAt = SystemTime.Now();

    unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

Here's the unit of work code:

```
public virtual void Commit()
{
    if (_isDisposed)
    {
        throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().Name);
    }

    _database.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I even went into the designer.cs file and put a breakpoint on the field that is being set but not updated. I stepped through and it entered and execute the `set` code, so the Entity should be getting "notified" of the change to this field:

```
public string CrmId
{
    get
    {
        return this._CrmId;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._CrmId != value))
        {
            this.OnCrmIdChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._CrmId = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("CrmId");
            this.OnCrmIdChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Other useful information:

- ObjectTracking is enabled
- No errors or exceptions when second SubmitChanges is called (just silently fails update)
- SQL profiler shows insert and select  but not the subsequent update statement. Linq-To-Sql is not generating the update statement.
- There is only one database, one database string, so the update is not going to another database
- The table has a primary key.

I don't know what would cause Linq-To-Sql to not issue the update command and not raise some kind of error. Perhaps the problem stems from using the same DataContext instance? I've even refreshed the object from the database using the DataContact.Refresh method before it is pulled for the update, but that didn't help.

Comment: Can you provide an MCVE for this?  Without any kind of code it leaves us guessing as to what could be going wrong.

Comment: You have to notify your entity that content has been modified. I believe in your case your entity is not aware of the changes that's why it ignores your command. Please provide code to help you as we are guessing what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Code has been provided. I use repository and factory patterns, so I don't know how useful this is. George, how can I notify my entity that is has changed?

Comment: we really need to see inside the unit of work to prove sumbitchanges is being called.

Comment: Added unit of work code. _database is an instance of DataContext.

Comment: you use ITransaction transaction = transactionRepository.FindById; perhaps this does not work with the datacontext? What happens if you explicitly use the Entity type or var ...

Comment: Pleun, sorry I don't understand what you suggesting. I should mention that 1,000s of lines of code use these patterns and approaches I am using here... the code is not experimental and logically, should be working.

Comment: Where do you set the context _database in UnitOfWork class ? It looks like it is not aware of the changes.

Comment: What happens if you try to manually [attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548978%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) your record in the select and update routine? You should get an error like 'Cannot attach an entity that already exists.' and if you don't, then either the record is being tracked by another datacontext or not being tracked at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have found what is likely to be the root cause. I am using Unity. The initial insert is being performed in a service class with a PerWebRequest lifetime. The  select and update is happening in a class with a Singleton lifetime. So my assumption that the DataContext instances are the same was incorrect.

So, in my class with the Singleton lifetime, I get a fresh instance of the database repository and perform the update and no problem.

Now I still don't know why the original code didn't work and my approach could still be considered more a workaround than a solution, but it did solve my problem and hopefully will be useful to others.